# Django loading initial data prevents errors being displayed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django page with a form. I have some view code which deals with the form as normal but prepopulates the form with initial data from the a user's session if available. This is so that when a user returns to this form they see previously selected options (yes, the form is quite extensive).

My views,py:

```
def myView(request):   
    ...
    form = ProjectInfoForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # process form, including a redirect
        ...

    # if there is form data in the session, let's use that
    # to initaliaze our from with data
    if key in request.session:
        form = ProjectInfoForm(
            initial={
                 'model': request.session.get('model'),
                 ...
            }
        )
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        ...
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

Problem is: if I load the session data then the page does not display any error messages. The form does fail validation, I am just not getting the any output. Is there some conflict here with `initial`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from that snippet, if the session data is found then you completely re-initialize the form: the original, validated instance, which contained the POST data and any errors, has now been disposed. Presumably you would want to only enter that second `if` if the request is not a POST.

Comment: Haha. I love it when it's that simple! Thanks Daniel.